# PyMongo Bulk does not return after inserting 12k documents

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I'm using pymongo 3.4 on macOS to bulk insert 12k big documents. Each doc is a piece of a time series with 365 values, so it's quite huge. I'm doing something like this:

```
bulk = db.test.initialize_unordered_bulk_op()
for i in range(1,12000):
  bulk.insert(TimeSeries.getDict(i))
bulk.execute()
```

The problem is that `bulk.execute()` does not return. Is there a kind of performance problem or a dimensional constraint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider putting your insert bulk operations into manageable batches of say 500 because write commands can accept no more than 1000 operations (from the **[docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#Write-Command-Operation-Limit-Size)**), you will have to split bulk operations into multiple batches, in this case you can choose an arbitrary batch size of up to 1000.

The reason for choosing 500 is to ensure that the sum of the associated document from the **[`Bulk.insert()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk.insert/#Bulk.insert)** is less than or equal to the **[maximum BSON document size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#BSON-Document-Size)**, even though there is no there is no guarantee using the default `1000` operations requests will fit under the 16MB BSON limit. The **[`Bulk()`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/bulk.html)** operations in the mongo shell and comparable methods in the drivers do not have this limit though.

Doing the math, you'd want to be sure those 500 insert operation requests themselves do not actually create a BSON document greater than 16MB i.e. for an input document with 365 values, you need to determine the scale factor that will bring the total size of documents to 16MB or less. To me it seems like 365x500 is a reasonable guess for a size to be under 16MB, unlike 365x12000:

```
bulk = db.test.initialize_unordered_bulk_op()
counter = 0

for i in range(1, 12000):
    # process in bulk
    bulk.insert(TimeSeries.getDict(i))
    counter += 1

    if (counter % 500 == 0):
        bulk.execute()
        bulk = db.test.initialize_unordered_bulk_op()

if (counter % 500 != 0):
    bulk.execute()
```

---

**--UPDATE--**

Actually, [the limit does not apply do the bulk API](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Write-Command-Operation-Limit-Size) but instead

> [If a group exceeds this limit, MongoDB will divide the group into
>   smaller groups of 1000 or less.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk/#ordered-operations)

Thanks to [@Styva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3100115/)ne for pointing this out.

Comment: Woah! It sounds good! But why dosen't the same problem happen in batch.find().update_one()?

Comment: In theory it should apply to all the methods in the bulk write operations. It's always best to batch up your updates, that way you can manage the bulk operations whilst letting the server do what's best, i.e. streamline the updates for you.

Comment: Yep! So I need to divide also bulk updates in batches of 500. Right?

Comment: Anyway, I think pymongo should raise an exception in case of any dimensional problem

Comment: Yes, 500 seems reasonable, even 1000, as long as you are sure the sum of the associated document from the bulk method is less than or equal to the maximum BSON document size. When you do `bulk.execute()` you should be able to see the write response in the results, this contains info about the number of operations which went through ok, errors etc

Comment: I have a last curiosity, this time about your code hint. Why did you use `if (counter % 500 != 0):` for the last bulk execution? I think if the counter arrived at a multiple of 500 at the end of the cycle, it would be executed in the last `for` iteration. So, when Python exits from the cycle, we have a counter value that is not a multiple of 500.

Comment: It can be removed safely since it doesn't do anything else but to clean up remaining operations in the queue e.g. if the for loop range limit was not a multiple of 500, e.g. `for i in range(1, 12400)`: then the first 12000 operations will be processed in the for loop and the bulk will execute 24 times. Now the remaining 400 operation will then be executed outside the loop since `counter >= 12001` which will satisfy the `(counter % 500 != 0)` condition and thus the last 25th bulk execution will be in that statement.

Comment: That's neat! I think that without the second if, all should be fine! Right?

Comment: Yes, it should be okay since you know all bulk updates are done within the loop => `12000 % 500 = 0`

Comment: Hi @chridam it is me again:) [recently, someone pointed out to me that the limit does not apply do the bulk API but instead](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Write-Command-Operation-Limit-Size) [*If a group exceeds this limit, MongoDB will divide the group into smaller groups of 1000 or less*](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk/#ordered-operations)

Comment: @Styvane Nice one!